# Jssor list-slider and X-Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor, x-editable

I have a Jssor list slider and I would like to make the thumbnail text editable in place with X-Editable:
[example](http://www.jssor.com/demos/list-slider.html)

Both functions work on the page together with separate elements, but I cannot find a way of causing the link text to become editable.
There are no errors, the text element simply does not show the pop-up editable box.

I presume this is because the class="t" declaration informs Jssor to control the thumb div interfering with X-editable's attempt to do the same.
X-Editable requires that the editable text be wrapped in an  element:

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

But this seems to be interfered with by Jssor.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

------------------UPDATED in response to answer------------------

Thanks for taking the time to help me out :)
I was unable to change the default behaviour from on click to onmousedown in the x-editable library, but I did find a work around to allow activation of the editable element with the click of another element external to the slider container.
In the body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('#doit').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#username').editable({
            send: 'never',  
            title: 'Enter text',
            placement: 'right',
            toggle: 'manual',
            display: function(value) {
                $('#username').text(value);
        }
    });
    $('#username').editable('toggle');

    });
});
```

...and the elements:

```
<span id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</span>
<a id="doit" href="#">testlink</a>
```

If the span is outside of the slider container clicking the testlink functions as expected and opens the pop-up editor input field, but once it is placed inside the slider:

```
<div class="t">
    <span id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</span>
</div>
```

...there is no response.
I looked for the function you highlighted and think I found the one you meant, 'ContentClickEventHandler', but clearing this function did not solve the problem.

Thanks again for you help, and for releasing this wonderful product to the likes of me :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following 3 approaches.

1. I guess `X-Editable` detects `click` event to make an element editable. If you can revise the library, please change the event from `click` to `mousedown`.
2. Not sure it would work or not, please have a good try.
   Add `nodrag="true"` for the link element.
3. Open jssor.slider.js, replace

   ```
   function SlidesClickEventHandler(event) {
       if (_LastDragSucceded) {
           $Jssor$.$StopEvent(event);

           var checkElement = $Jssor$.$EventSrc(event);
           while (checkElement && _SlidesContainer !== checkElement) {
               if (checkElement.tagName == "A") {
                   $Jssor$.$CancelEvent(event);
               }
               try {
                   checkElement = checkElement.parentNode;
               } catch (e) {
                   // Firefox sometimes fires events for XUL elements, which throws
                   // a "permission denied" error. so this is not a child.
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   function SlidesClickEventHandler(event) {
   }
   ```